# Tasks created with create_task that are never awaited, seem to break expectations of cancelation for child tasks

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Imagine we're writing an application which allows a user to run an application (let's say it's a series of important operations against an API) continuously, and can run multiple applications concurrently. Requirements include:

- the user can control the number of concurrent applications (which may limit concurrent load against an API, which is often important)
- if the OS tries to close the Python program running this thing, it should gracefully terminate, allowing any in-progress applications to complete their run before closing

The question here is specifically about the task manager we've coded, so let's stub out some code that illustrates this problem:

```
import asyncio
import signal


async def work_chunk():
    """Simulates a chunk of work that can possibly fail"""
    await asyncio.sleep(1)


async def protected_work():
    """All steps of this function MUST complete, the caller should shield it from cancelation."""
    print("protected_work start")
    for i in range(3):
        await work_chunk()
        print(f"protected_work working... {i+1} out of 3 steps complete")
    print("protected_work done... ")


async def subtask():
    print("subtask: starting loop of protected work...")
    cancelled = False
    while not cancelled:
        protected_coro = asyncio.create_task(protected_work())
        try:
            await asyncio.shield(protected_coro)
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            cancelled = True
            await protected_coro
    print("subtask: cancelation complete")


async def subtask_manager():
    """
    Manage a pool of subtask workers. 
    (In the real world, the user can dynamically change the concurrency, but here we'll 
    hard code it at 3.)
    """
    tasks = {}
    while True:
        for i in range(3):
            task = tasks.get(i)
            if not task or task.done():
                tasks[i] = asyncio.create_task(subtask())
        await asyncio.sleep(5)


def shutdown(signal, main_task):
    """Cleanup tasks tied to the service's shutdown."""
    print(f"Received exit signal {signal.name}. Scheduling cancelation:")
    main_task.cancel()


async def main():
    print("main... start")
    coro = asyncio.ensure_future(subtask_manager())
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    loop.add_signal_handler(signal.SIGINT, lambda: shutdown(signal.SIGINT, coro))
    loop.add_signal_handler(signal.SIGTERM, lambda: shutdown(signal.SIGTERM, coro))
    await coro
    print("main... done")


def run():
    asyncio.run(main())


run()
```

`subtask_manager` manages a pool of workers, periodically looking up what the present concurrency requirement is and updating the number of active workers appropriately (note that the code above cuts out most of that, and just hard codes a number, since it isn't important to the question).

`subtask` is the worker loop itself, which continuously runs `protected_work()` until someone cancels it.

But this code is broken. When you give it a SIGINT, the whole thing immediately crashes.

[image: Screenshot of log output from invoking run(), illustrating that CancelledError is raised in the "except" block of the subtask function.]

Before I explain further, let me point you at a critical bit of code:

```
1   protected_coro = asyncio.create_task(protected_work())
2   try:
3       await asyncio.shield(protected_coro)
4   except asyncio.CancelledError:
5       cancelled = True
6       await protected_coro  # <-- This will raise CancelledError too!
```

After some debugging, we find that our try/except block isn't working. We find that *both* line 3 AND line 6 raise CancelledError.

When we dig in further, we find that ALL "await" calls throw CancelledError after the subtask manager is canceled, not just the line noted above. (i.e., the second line of work_chunk(), `await asyncio.sleep(1)`, and the 4th line of protected_work(), `await work_chunk()`, *also* raise CancelledError.)

What's going on here?

It would seem that Python, for some reason, isn't propagating cancelation as you would expect, and just throws up its hands and says "I'm canceling everything now".

*Why?*

Clearly, I don't understand how cancelation propagation works in Python. I've struggled to find documentation on how it works. Can someone describe to me how cancelation is propagated in a clear-minded way that explains the behavior found in the example above?

Answer (score 1):

After looking at this problem for a long time, and experimenting with other code snippets (where cancelation propagation works as expected), I started to wonder if the problem is Python doesn't *know* the order of propagation *here*, in *this* case.

But why?

Well, `subtask_manager` creates tasks, but doesn't await them.

Could it be that Python doesn't assume that the coroutine that created that task (with `create_task`) owns that task? I *think* Python uses the `await` keyword *exclusively* to know in what order to propagate cancelation, and if after traversing the whole tree of tasks it finds tasks that still haven't been canceled, it just destroys them all.

Therefore, it's up to us to manage Task cancelation propagation ourselves, in any place where we know we haven't awaited an async task. So, we need to refactor `subtask_manager`  to catch its own cancelation, and explicitly cancel *and then await* all its child tasks:

```
async def subtask_manager():
    """
    Manage a pool of subtask workers. 
    (In the real world, the user can dynamically change the concurrency, but here we'll 
    hard code it at 3.)
    """
    tasks = {}
    while True:
        for i in range(3):
            task = tasks.get(i)
            if not task or task.done():
                tasks[i] = asyncio.create_task(subtask())
        try:
            await asyncio.sleep(5)
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            print("cancelation detected, canceling children")
            [t.cancel() for t in tasks.values()]
            await asyncio.gather(*[t for t in tasks.values()])
            return
```

Now our code works as expected:

[image: Working log output.]

*Note: I've answered my own question Q&A style, but I still feel unsatisfied with my textual answer about how cancelation propagation works. If anyone has a better explanation of how cancelation propagation works, I would love to read it.*

Answer (score 1):

> What's going on here? It would seem that Python, for some reason, isn't propagating cancelation as you would expect, and just throws up its hands and says "I'm canceling everything now".

TL;DR Canceling everything is precisely what's happening, simply because the event loop is exiting.

To investigate this, I changed the invocation of `add_signal_handler()` to `loop.call_later(.5, lambda: shutdown(signal.SIGINT, coro))`. Python's <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> handling has [odd corners](https://vorpus.org/blog/control-c-handling-in-python-and-trio/), and I wanted to check whether the strange behavior is the result of that. But the bug was perfectly reproducible without signals, so it wasn't that.

And yet, asyncio cancellation really shouldn't work like your code shows. Canceling a task propagates to the future (or another task) it awaits, but `shield` is specifically implemented to circumvent that. It creates and returns a fresh future, and connects the result of the original (shielded) future to the new one in a way that `cancel()` doesn't know how to follow.

It took me some time to unearth what really happens, and that is:

- `await coro` at the end of main awaits the task that gets cancelled, so it gets a `CancelledError` as soon as `shutdown` cancels it;
- the exception causes `main` to exit and enters the cleanup sequence at the end of `asyncio.run()`. This cleanup sequence cancels **all** tasks, including the ones you've shielded.

You can test it by changing `await coro` at the end of `main()` to:

```py
try:
    await coro
finally:
    print('main... done')
```

And you will see that "main... done" is printed prior to all the mysterious cancellations you've been witnessing.

So that clears the mystery and to fix the issue, you should postpone exiting `main` until everything is done. For example, you can create the `tasks` dict in `main`, pass it to `subtask_manager()`, and then await those critical tasks when the main task gets cancelled:

```py
async def subtask_manager(tasks):
    while True:
        for i in range(3):
            task = tasks.get(i)
            if not task or task.done():
                tasks[i] = asyncio.create_task(subtask())

        try:
            await asyncio.sleep(5)
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            for t in tasks.values():
                t.cancel()
            raise

# ... shutdown unchanged

async def main():
    print("main... start")
    tasks = {}
    main_task = asyncio.ensure_future(subtask_manager(tasks))
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    loop.add_signal_handler(signal.SIGINT, lambda: shutdown(signal.SIGINT, main_task))
    loop.add_signal_handler(signal.SIGTERM, lambda: shutdown(signal.SIGTERM, main_task))
    try:
        await main_task
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks.values())
    finally:
        print("main... done")
```

Note that the main task must explicitly cancel its subtasks because that actually wouldn't happen automatically. Cancellation is propagated through a chain of `await`s, and `subtask_manager` doesn't explicitly awaits its subtasks, it just spawns them and awaits something else, effectively shielding them.